# Windows Installer database inspection?

Tags: windows, installation

Does anybody know of a tool that allow me to inspect what files an installer just added to a system after it ran?

Its sounds like this should be something that should exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick googling came up with [Total Uninstall](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Uninstallers/Total-Uninstall.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's too late you could use a tool such as process monitor or run the installer with logging:

> msiexec /i the.msi /log install.log

If you want to inspect an MSI database you can run ORCA from the windows installer SDK. You can find information about installed files, registry and other actions.

Comment: Using process monitor can indeed be helpful to see exactly what the installer is doing, but it may be tricky to figure out exactly the resulting changes to the system.